# Firebase - https triggered cloud function with router dont reply response

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm currently trying to create a `firebase` cloud function using routes.

Here the simple code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

// Create an Express object and routes (in order)
const app = express();

app.get('/TOTO', (req, res) => {
  console.log("GET TOTO")
  res.status(200).send("TOTO")
})


// Set our GCF handler to our Express app.
exports.work = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When i'm executing it, the curl don't give any response, but it should return me "TOTO"...

When i check the logs, the console.log("GET TOTO") is executed, so i don't understand why the res return is not send back to my curl client...

Here the logs :

```
2020-02-07T10:18:41.371688612Z D work: Function execution started
2020-02-07T10:18:41.378Z I work: GET TOTO
2020-02-07T10:18:41.379530391Z D work: Function execution took 8 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

Here is the curl :

```
curl  -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"  -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XGET "https://${CLOUDFUNCTION_URL}/work/TOTO" -D -
```

and the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
etag: W/"4-7vr2vtrI8PWK9QfOP94qG3exzYk"
function-execution-id: pnbz2w7zg1zk
x-powered-by: Express
x-cloud-trace-context: 8d739b31bd309bffb0ecb9294e12028d;o=1
date: Fri, 07 Feb 2020 10:32:36 GMT
server: Google Frontend
content-length: 4
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

Node js runtime : nodejs8

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried to add return, no return, async, no async... but i don't figure it out

Thanks.

Comment: from the response you shared I can see the length is 4 so I guess the issue is on how you are getting the content. How are you doing this step?

Comment: the problem was my zsh ... directly after the curl, it override the body response... don't know if a problem with virtualbox (i'm on a ubuntu vm) or zsh itself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my zsh ... directly after the curl, it overwrite the body response in the sdout with the next prompt...

with bash, no problem.